# No inherent amplitude loss for AC across a capacitor, right?

Tags: capacitor, ac

*This is a bad question unless "misconceptions in learning" is a topic that people here would like. The topic of common misconceptions is pretty common here, and often appears in questions or answers. Feel free to close or delete, or whatever those with moderator privileges feel like, I already had the question resolved for myself. If so, maybe you could create the tag "learning-errors" and add it to this question, I can't because I lack 300 reputation.*

I have learned about high-pass and low-pass RC filters. Initially, it seemed like loss of amplitude was inherent to AC passing a capacitor, in the same way that it is with phase shift. But this isn't the case, right? Amplitude loss is instead caused by combination of a resistor and capacitor. Is there no inherent loss of amplitude for AC passing through a capacitor in itself (as in a circuit with just a capacitor)? If anyone needs a schematic of the circuit just described, *a circuit with just a capacitor*, here it is:

[image]

(5 or so people actually requested that one be added because it was apparently impossible to understand otherwise. )

The context that the "inherent amplitude loss" meme was presented, was alongside an inherent effect that is actually true, the 90° phase shift inherent to capacitors when using AC. In AC, "the current leads the voltage by 90°", under some ideal conditions. I managed to pick up that the amplitude loss in RC filters and such, was also inherent to capacitor, which is false. To be clear on it, I asked here. As stated, this is a dumb question, because it is not about something that is right, but about something that is wrong. I pointed that out in the beginning of the question so that no one got taken by surprise on that.

[image]

My suggestion to this community, if this question is to be redeemed, is to add the tag "learning-errors", tag it with that. But I don't know if electricalengineering stack exchange wants to focus on that topic, I just know that it is often brought up in different questions and answers. Or leave it closed, who cares.

To give some credit to my claim that this might be a common "learning-error", I just saw the quote *"reactive circuit elements always introduce phase shift in addition to amplitude effect"* ([source](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/low-pass-filter-tutorial-basics-passive-RC-filter/)), and it sure seems to suggest capacitors, as a reactive element, would have an **inherent** amplitude effect, which they do not in a "pure capacitance" circuit if I understand right. So it is possible although maybe hard to see that it might be reasonable that beginners might interpret that in the way I did. Semantically, "always introduce amplitude effects" can easily be interpreted to mean what it actually means, and I asked because I wanted to be clear that this claim was false, which it is. There is no inherent amplitude loss for AC across a capacitor.

Comment: Please draw a schematic and show the signals you want to compare.

Comment: No the schematic is understood anyway. The question isn't schematic specific. Just consider an AC generator + capacitor if you want a schematic, but it can be answered anyway.

Comment: It's more conceptual.

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, you're looking for what a capacitor does in isolation... but if all you have is a capacitor, hanging off the end of a signal generator (or even connected across a signal generator), you aren't going to have any amplitude change. However, a resistor would have the same properties in that configuration....

Comment: I'm mostly just interested in what does what and why. Have been trying to understand the phase shift, that is pretty easy I think it seems like except why it is only partial at one extreme. But, I was also wondering about the amplitude loss, because it seemed "inherent". Then I got that it was caused by the pressure drop between resistor and capacitor. To clear out that there was any magical amplitude loss associated with the capacitor itself specifically, I asked here (because how I had gotten it explained to me before it seemed like it. )

Comment: What do you mean by "a circuit with just a capacitor"? What do you mean by "AC passing a capacitor"? What do you mean by "combination of resistor and capacitor"? You really need to add some schematics, because your language is very vague.

Comment: What do you mean by "amplitude loss"? There is a voltage across the capacitor. There is also current through it. But "amplitude loss" is an insufficiently clear term.

Comment: Sorry, the schematic is not understood anyway. Please add one.

Comment: No I think it works without schematic. I got the impression that capacitors when AC current passes over them have a phase shift component and amplitude loss component. But, as I learnt the details a bit more, it seems like there is no amplitude loss, but that one can be created by using resistors to produce voltage drop effect relative to output.

Comment: Well, what I mean with amplitude loss, is that I got a general impression first that with capacitors, there is phase shift component and amplitude loss component. But, as I looked more at it, here does not seem to be any inherent amplitude loss component, but one can be created by adding more components than just the capacitor, a resistor more specifically (or more stuff but minimum. )

Comment: It's not really a question about a specific schematic. More that I misunderstood a concept that was taught, or, it was taught wrongly. I agree it is best to ask specific questions, I think the issue I had might be that sometimes concepts are taught in a generalized way to the point of them being wrong, or how they are explained is misunderstod.

Comment: This circuit could be used as an example but I don't think a circuit is needed, https://i.imgur.com/xRu8fHa.png. The point was that amplitude loss that I got impression was caused by capacitors seems to not be so, but something that can be achieved by combining capacitors with resistors etc.

Comment: That the question was closed, it was more of a "misconceptions when learning" question, I think. And this might be wrong place for that, I just prefer myself to not learn wrong and avoid getting any false baggage, so I wanted to be clear on it for myself.

Comment: I think the issue is that you are using phrasing that is non-standard and/or ambiguous, and we need some more details to pin down what exactly you're asking. I'm not saying that I expect every beginner to know everything first, but you will get much better responses if you can give specific examples. The way you were describing the circuit I can think of a few ways of drawing it, and each results in a different answer. Your schematic was one of the possibilities, but not the one I thought you meant. I'll put that schematic you added in - that helps a bunch.

Comment: I agree. It was a bad question. It is more about "misconceptions in learning", it is really common that people learn something wrong or misunderstand it, and there are trends there too. When I was learning about capacitors in AC, the content made it seem like they had an inherent amplitude loss effect, just like they do have an inherent 90° voltage phase shift effect from that the voltage is the derivative or change in voltage, and not highest at the peaks but in between them.

Comment: Fact: Capacitors in AC do have inherent phase shift effect, current leads voltage by 90°
Fiction: Capacitors in AC have inherent amplitude loss effect

In my interpretation of the learning material, the two were presented as being the same type of inherent properties. I can't say for sure that it was actually presented that way, it might have been, or I might have just misunderstood it.

Comment: The point of the schematic is to at least provide *something* concrete to make reference to instead of the shifting sea of words, because it's not that what you've said is wrong or a misconception, it's just that *none of that big pile of words can be interpreted to relate to the real world in any meaningful way*.

Comment: there wasn't a sea of words. it was a few sentences. one was "a circuit with just a capacitor". you are just trying to push nonsense instead of talking about the question objectively. yes it is a bad question, it is a bad question because it is about a common learning-error, and this SE might not be focused around that topic. also, if someone now deletes this comment because I said "you push nonsense", well, then do so.

Comment: @Ohm Hey, Ohm. I was going to reopen the question but there are a few problems. 1) It's better if there is no discussion in the question, so if you could edit the question and remove non essential discussion that would be better 2) It would be better if the question actually asked a question 3) You have created a near-duplicate question, please delete one question OR we can leave one closed and point one to the other. Thanks

Comment: And no I have no "duplicate question". I asked an actually good question now. Like I already said, if "learning errors" questions are off topic, then eradicate this one, don't care. If not, then add the learning errors tag perhaps. I already resolved what I wondered about.

Comment: (The only reason you would have to keep "is amplitude loss inherent to capacitors" is if you think it adds any value to anyone else who might have the same questions. This is what collaborative question and answer sites are about. I already resolved what I wondered about. There was no reason to close it, if you think there is any reason to open it, since nothing has changed. It was a bad question, unless "learning-errors" is an appropriate topic. )

Comment: The idea that adding a drawing with a generator and capacitor "made it a good question", well, no. It did not. I have no interest in charades. Don't care about that.

Comment: If I were a moderator, I would delete this question if I did not think "learning errors" was appropriate for this SE. And I would allow it to exist otherwise. Anything in between, I do not care about.

Answer (score 2):

A schematic is better than words - no matter how simple it is.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fG1z3y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. As far as V1 is concerned the loads presented by C1-R1 and R2-C2 are identical.*

The circuit of R2-C2 should make it intuitively obvious that there will be a phase shift due to the charging of C2 via R2 and that it will lag V1.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3mAMV.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. If the circuit is not loaded (or a very high impedance load is connected such as a voltmeter) then no significant current will flow and the output voltage will be in phase with the source, there will be no amplitude drop and the output voltage will be the same as V1.

Comment: What I take with me is that there is no amplitude loss with a capacitor in itself. Some other thing I thought about, the " phase shift due to the charging of C2 via R2", is it the same as the 90° phase shift from current flowing mostly when capacitor charges and discharges, and not at the voltage peaks of the AC current? Or, are there two different components to the phase shift that is usually talked about? I thought about that for days now, can't entirely say what is what.

Answer (score 2):

Components which have two terminals, and which are *linear* have an *impedance*. The impedance is the (phasor) ratio between the current through the component and the voltage drop across the component.

Capacitors, like resistors and inductors, have impedances, and those impedances depend upon frequencies.

Networks with three or more terminals can have properties that are more complex than impedances. For example, the network enclosed in the box below has three terminals, and it makes sense to speak of the "amplitude loss" between the input voltage (relative to ground) and the output voltage (relative to ground).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8uUP9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What you may mean by amplitude loss in the case of a two-terminal component, I do not know. Amplitude *loss* implies that there are two amplitudes being related. What are these two amplitudes? That question needs to be answered before one can meaningfully answer the question of whether or not capacitors have "amplitude loss".

You *could* mean that an (ideal) capacitor does not convert electrical power into heat. If that is what you mean, then that is true. A resistor converts electrical power into heat, but an ideal capacitor does not. (Nor does an ideal inductor). For this reason, the impedance of these components is called *reactive* rather than *resistive*.

Comment: I get that capacitors impede current and that is is frequency dependent, lower impedance at higher frequencies. And that the circuit you show is a low-pass RC filter, because there is less pressure drop over the resistor when the impedance of C1 is high at low frequencies. It was just that I had capacitors explained to me (based on my own limited understanding) in a way that made it seem like they had an inherent amplitude loss effect. Learning wrong is usually a bad idea, so, I just asked to clarify that it was wrong.

Comment: Again, what would be the meaning of "amplitude loss" for a two terminal component? Amplitude loss implies that there are _two_ amplitudes being related. What are these two amplitudes?

Comment: I'm saying that the concept of "inherent amplitude loss" probably makes no sense because it is probably false. I either misunderstood, or had it explained, wrongly, and when I looked more at the details I noticed that. "Misconceptions in learning" questions might be better fit elsewhere, although that is a pretty common topic on this forum too, I see it mentioned in lots of questions or answers.

Comment: (I think how I phrased the question it is clear it is a "misconception in learning" question, but I get if that is not the type of questions that should be asked here. )

Comment: The question was closed because it needs clarity, and cannot be meaningfully answered without this clarity. If you are willing to clarify, you are welcome to request that the question be re-opened. But remember, clarity begins with a schematic.

Comment: Well it's closed because it is not a very good question. Unless seen from "misconceptions in learning", that is actually fairly common topic. I think it has been meaningfully answered. And no, schematic was not needed in this case, and yes schematics are often good.

Comment: In this case, a schematic would have helped clarify, whether you believe so or not.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you want to think of it.

If you have a high pass RC filter, and feed it high frequency sine wave, impedance of capacitor is near zero so there is no voltage loss over capacitor since it is so small compared to resistor.

If you feed the same filter with low frequency sine wave, impedance of capacitor is not zero so it is a voltage divider with the resistor so amplitude is smaller as there will be voltage drop over the capacitor.

Another way to look at is in time domain. High frequency sine wave is so fast changing that capacitor does not have much time to build up charge and thus accumulate voltage over it. Low frequency sine wave changes so slowly that capacitor has time to charge and accumulate voltage over it.

On the other hand, if you put an ideal AC source over an ideal capacitance, the voltage of the capacitance is always at same voltage and phase with the source, it's just that neither exist in the real world.

Comment: Yes I understand that, the hi pass / low pass RC filters. It took me a few days to get them, but once I got it it is really easy. But what I wanted to clear up is that I got the impression that some amplitude loss was caused by the capacitor itself, specifically. This seems to be false, but I entirely get how capacitors combined with resistors can produce amplitude loss on output signal.